# How can I toggle Full Screen mode in Remote Desktop without a Break key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, netbook

My small laptop has a small keyboard, which lacks a Pause/Break key. Ctrl-Alt-Break toggles Full Screen mode in Windows Remote Desktop. Without a Break key, how can I enter Full Screen mode?

I know I can *exit* fullscreen mode with the mouse.

Maximizing the window doesn't help.

This matters more on small laptops because the screens are small (so you need all the real estate you can get) and because the keyboard lacks dedicated PgUp/PgDn and other dedicated keys (so I can't easily use the RDP alternatives like Alt-PgUp).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have break as a Fn?

Comment: That's weird; maximizing the window makes RDP go full-screen for me, everywhere I use it. What happens when you maximize yours?  Also, there's almost certainly a way to send Break; what make and model of netbook is it?

Comment: If the resolution of the local screen is smaller than the resolution of the remote PC, then maximizing will not make it go full screen, as you'd lose the scroll bars.

Comment: @boot13 - RDP always *used* to go full screen but since v6.0 it maximises when the screen resolution and mstsc resolution both match, instead of going full screen. It's so *bleeping* irritating, as my boss's new laptop doesn't have a `break` key, meaning I have to watch him clunk around scrolling up and down every time he needs to get to the start bar.

Comment: I even tried the Windows On-Screen Keyboard and had no luck. OP's own answer is my favorite.

Comment: Acer Nitro 5's don't have a break key, and I can't find an alternative. Argh.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known issue with systems running Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 whose resolution is set at 1366×768. Microsoft has created a hotfix which you can read about / request here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2582172

If you're lazy or don't want to give MS your email, you can just download it from [here](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix377500/7600/free/435474_intl_x64_zip.exe). Just know that by doing so Microsoft will have no way of notifying you if there is a recall on the fix.

Answer (score 21):

I have a Lenovo E430 and was struggling with this very issue.  None of the answers here worked for me because <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> does not equal Break on this keyboard. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is the shortcut.

As such, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> maximizes the RDC window.

[Source](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Lenovo/ThinkPad-Edge-E430/Manual/310125)

Comment: In my experience, pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Fn+B` altogether often failed. Here is how I do it: hold `Ctrl+Alt` first, then press `Fn+B`.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Fn+B perfect!

Comment: Works fine 10 years later on Dell Latitude 5590 laptop keyboard running Windows 10

Answer (score 8):

Some alternatives for laptops where you do not find Break key:

On a Dell Latitude 6420 and others, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

On an HP Envy, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>pause</kbd>

On HP Probook 4440s and others, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>. This is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

On Lenovo E430, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.  Hold Ctrl+Alt first, then press Fn+B.

Comment: Works on my Dell Latitude also!

Comment: My current HP Envy has neither `pause` nor `insert`. Best I've found so far is CRTL + ALT + HOME which selects the pin icon in the blue RDP bar. From there I can WIN + D or Tab twice and hit Enter to minimize, or do other things like ALT + TAB.

Answer (score 4):

I used AutoHotKey as recommended in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/184324/how-to-add-a-pause-break-key-to-a-keyboard-that-doesnt-have-one) to map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>break</kbd> using this binding: `CapsLock::CtrlBreak`

AutoHotKey needs to be running for the binding to hold.  It is not a simple registry change that can be done with most other keys.

Answer (score 3):

In HP laptops you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>. This is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

Its working with HP Probook series. I am using HP Probook 4440s

[Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you could find a configuration option for mstsc.exe that lets you change that setting.. Or possibly a reg edit.

If you have some key you don't really use, you could remap it to function as a break key. You can use any of a large number of windows programs to remap keyboard keys. [This article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remap-keyboard-free-tools-windows/) discusses 3 such applications.

Comment: Except that break is a special key and can't be mapped onto another key.  (Owner of a brand new samsung laptop that has a numeric keypad, but no pause/break key.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in full screen mode and you minimize, and then restore, it comes back in full-screen mode. So I've learned to always minimize, and not de-maximize from the panel that slides down at the top of the RDP screen.

I also made it easy to reconnect if I lose my full-screen state. First, I RDP to each machine and save credentials. (Only do this if you're on a secure machine). Second, I create a small batch file that looks like this:

```
start mstsc /v:%~n0 /f
```

I name the batch file after the computer I want to connect to. I put this in an easy-to-reach location (I have a dedicated toolbar on my task bar). Now, when I loose my fullscreen state, I just rerun this batch file and a few seconds later I'm back in full screen.

Comment: Your advice to just minimize will help me in the future. Your batch file one liner saved my bacon just now. Simplified, that looks like `start mstsc /v:10.1.1.10 /v` if your target computer is 10.1.1.10. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Other have addressed the symptom, but to address the underlying question/issue, are you absolutely certain that your laptop does not have a <kbd>Break</kbd> key? Even *netbooks* usually [have one](http://images.google.com/search?q=netbook%20keyboard&sout=1&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l); if it doesn’t get its own key, it usually shares one with <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Perhaps it is simply not printed on the key (particularly common with after-market/replacement/generic keyboards).

You did not mention the make/model of the laptop, but check the manual/docs to see if you have to do anything special to signal that key such as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Unless the manufacturer is really trying to cut costs, it is usually included because as sean mentioned, [<kbd>Break</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key) is a special key. It is similar to how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is/was specially handled by the keyboard controller at a hardware level (a direct line to the reset pin on the CPU).

Comment: Or it could be like [mine](http://www.laptopskeyboard.com/4303-10054-thickbox/replacement-for-hp-pavilion-g4-g6-keyboard.jpg), where my right `Shift` key is also labelled `Pause` and functions as a `Break` key when pressed with `Fn` held. Yes, that's convoluted.

Comment: Yup; most of the keys are usually there and just require some weird two- (or more) key chord. Most of the time when they want to cut costs, they instead just cut the extra (usually the right) modifier (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Win) keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check that F Lock isn't/is turned on. My break key doesn't work unless F Lock is turned off.

(P.S. I hope the person who invented F Lock got their just desserts)