# Simulate key combination

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have a keyboard with no <kbd>break</kbd> key. Is there a means (install software or otherwise) to send a <kbd>break</kbd> keypress event to a machine with no break key? I'm fine using AutoHotKey or something.

Specifically, I want to toggle full screen mode on a hyper-v server.  There is no way to switch the keyboard shortcut to accomplish this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd>.

#### Painful extra details that most people can ignore

I do not want to use the windows touch keyboard. I am looking for a faster way to get to the break key. I'm using 3 keyboards. I can simply reach for one of the keyboards that has a break key, but again the goal here is efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your keyboard

> #### Keyboards without Break key
>
> Compact and notebook keyboards often do not have a dedicated <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key. These may use the following substitutes for <kbd>Break</kbd>:
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on certain Lenovo laptops and certain Dell laptops.
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> on Samsung.
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on certain Dell laptops.
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> on certain HP laptops.
>
> Substitutes for <kbd>Pause</kbd>:
>
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on certain Lenovo laptops).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Keyboards_without_Break_key

If the keyboard has no facilities to simulate the <kbd>Break</kbd> key then there are several other solutions. The easiest way is to remap some unused key to <kbd>Break</kbd>.

Alternatively you can use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). The following script will remap the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key to <kbd>Break</kbd>

```
RAlt::^Pause
```

See also

- [How to add a Pause/Break key to a keyboard that doesn't have one?](https://superuser.com/q/184324/241386)

Comment: Its a Logitech K811.  Fn + p was tried and did not work.

Comment: some keyboards have no way to press ctrl+break. The only way is remap the shortcut or simulate using autohotkey

Comment: Remapping a key could for example be done with SharpKeys https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys

Comment: @bugybunny yes, that's been answered in the link I gave above

Comment: @phuclv I know, I saw that but I doubt every reader of this answer will also click on the link and read the other answer. So I wanted to include this additional information here.